# Finding all Pythagorean triples using Euclid's formula

Tags: c++, pythagorean

The goal of this program is to find all Pythagorean triples for each value (a, b, c) less than 500 using Euclid's formula (a = m^2 -n^2, b = 2mn, c = m^2 + n^2.) So here's my code.

```
int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock()/ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);

    for (int m = 1; m <= 500; m++)
    {

        for (int n = 1; n <= 500; n++)
        {

            int a = (m*m)-(n*n);
            int b = 2*m*n;
            int c = (m*m)+(n*n);
            if (m > n && a + b == c)
            {
                cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t finish = clock()/ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
cout << "completed in " <<clock() << " ms";
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this and my output is nothing. The way I thought it'd work was: for every integer m less than/equal to 500 and starting at 1, add one to m each time. Same deal for n. Then plug those values into the formula and if a+b == c, it prints those values, thus finding my triples. But I'm not getting any output.

Comment: Save extra `a,b,c` calculations by setting your `for` loop appropriately:  `for (m = 2; m <= 500; m++)` and `for (n = 1; n < m; n++)` to get rid of the first clause of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
a + b = (m^2 + 2mn - n^2) = (m+n)^2 - 2n^2
c = m^2 + n^2 = (m+n)^2 - 2mn
```

You required `a + b = c`

```
--> 2n^2 = 2mn
--> m = n
```

Since you also required `m > n`, you cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong: you're trying to get

> (m^2 - n^2) + 2mn = (m^2 + n^2)
>
> (m - n)^2 = m^2 + n^2

but for `n > 0` you will always have the following strict inequality:

> (m - n)^2 < m^2 < m^2 + n^2

According to wikipedia, you wanted to check whether the sum of squares was equal -

> (a^2 + b^2) == c^2

Answer (score 0):

You made a couple mistakes in your implementation (see fix below):

```
int main()
{
    for (int n = 1; n <= 500; ++n) // note the swap for the loops
    {
        for (int m = n + 1; m <= 500 && (m*m + n*n) <= 500; ++m) // note that m starts at n + 1
        {
            int a = (m*m)-(n*n);
            int b = 2*m*n;
            int c = (m*m)+(n*n);
            // Euclid already proved this, so there is no need to test it.
            std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. Euclid's formula requires `m > n`, so there is no need to check values that don't meet that criteria
2. Your test `(a + b) == c` will never work anyway.  The formula is `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` - that does not mean `a + b = c`.

Comment: I adjusted my code to fix my dumb errors (Haha I don't know how I missed that I need to check a^2+b^2 == c^2) but now I'm getting an infinite loop. Or at least a very, very long program. And just checking a sampling of the outputs reveals they're not perfect squares.

Comment: @Santa If you never want numbers over 500 (that is, the highest number in the triple would be 500), just limit `c` to 500 - which you can do in the conditional check of the inner for-loop.  All of the results from this formula will be Pythagorean Triples.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem; in the final iteration of the program I have to restrict c to <= 500:

```
int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock()/ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);

    for (int n = 1; n <= 500; n++)
    {
        for (int m = n+1; m <= 500; m++)
        {
            int a = (m*m)-(n*n);
            int b = 2*m*n;
            int c = (m*m)+(n*n);
            if ((a*a) + (b*b) == (c*c) && c <= 500)
            {
                cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t finish = clock()/ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
cout << "completed in " <<clock() << " ms";
    return 0;
}
```

That way the program doesn't go long like I was having problems with. Thank you all!

Comment: You should move the check to the inner loop's condition to avoid doing iterations that are unnecessary:  `for(int m = n + 1; m < = 500 && (m*m + n*n) <=500; ++m)`.  And the if-condition inside your inner loop is also unnecessary - mathematically, any `a`, `b`, and `c` produced will satisfy the condition.